# Why i am not getting the correct output?

Tags: html, css

HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    background-color: green;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:80vw;
    height:80vh;
}
```

In the above code I am trying to align my div content to display in the center but it is not displaying what changes should I make to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add height for the `body`.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same flex command you must add a height property.
For example:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```